# Python Pandas Sum specific columns while matching keys

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working with a data-stream that updates every 30 seconds with highway probe data. The data in the database needs to aggregate the incoming data and provide a 15 minute total. The issue I am encountering is trying to sum specific columns while matching keys.

```
Current_DataFrame:
uuid    lane-Number    lane-Status    lane-Volume    lane-Speed    lane-Class1Count    laneClass2Count
1       1              GOOD           10             55            5                   5
1       2              GOOD           5              57            3                   2
2       1              GOOD           7              45            4                   3

New_Dataframe:
uuid    lane-Number    lane-Status    lane-Volume    lane-Speed    lane-Class1Count    laneClass2Count
1       1              BAD            7              59            6                   1
1       2              GOOD           4              64            2                   2
2       1              BAD            5              63            3                   2

Goal_Dataframe:
uuid    lane-Number    lane-Status    lane-Volume    lane-Speed    lane-Class1Count    laneClass2Count
1       1              BAD            17             59            11                  6
1       2              GOOD           9              64            5                   4
2       1              BAD            12             63            7                   5
```

The goal is to match the dataframes on the uuid and lane-Number, and then to take the New_Dataframe values for lane-Status and lane-Speed, and then sum the lane-Volume, lane-Class1Count and laneClass2Count together. I want to keep all the new incoming data, unless it is aggregative (i.e. Number of cars passing the road probe) in which case I want to sum it together.

Comment: Did you try to join first the old and new dataframe using `uuid and lane-Number` and groupby the joined data and sum columns`lane-Volume, lane-Class1Count and laneClass2Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after some more digging.

```py
df = pd.concat(["new_dataframe", "current_dataframe"], ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby(["uuid", "lane-Number"]).agg(
{
    "lane-Status": "first",
    "lane-Volume": "sum",
    "lane-Speed": "first",
    "lane-Class1Count": "sum",
    "lane-Class2Count": "sum"   
})
```

By concatenating the  `current_dataframe` onto the back of the `new_dataframe` I can use the `first` aggregation option to get the newest data, and then sum the necessary rows.